# MySQL empty set with concat

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

When I use this query, it return ID of user, and separated address.
But I want to return empty set if address or email_verified_at is NULL or empty. How can I do this.

```
    SELECT u.id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(w.address separator ';')  as address 
    FROM users AS u 
    LEFT JOIN user_address AS w 
    ON u.id = w.user_id 
    WHERE u.name = 'name' AND 
    u.email_verified_at IS NOT NULL AND 
    address IS NOT NULL;
```

But I want to return empty set if address or email_verified_at is NULL or empty. How can I do this.

```
| name | id | email_verified_at |
| ---- | - | ------------------- |
| test | 1 | 2022-09-14 00:53:08 |


| user_id | address |
| - | -------------- |
| 1 | www.google.com |
| 1 | www.test.com |
| 1 | www.test2.com |
```

Comment: Could you give an example of sample data with nulls and your expected result, please?

Comment: you exclude all adresses that are NULL

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, that's not remotely what OP was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` with empty `SELECT` values `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT u.id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(w.address separator ';') AS address 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN user_address w 
  ON u.id = w.user_id 
WHERE u.name = 'name' 
  AND u.email_verified_at IS NOT NULL 
  AND w.address IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id
 UNION 
SELECT 
  '' AS id,
  '' AS address
LIMIT 1;
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6kFvgpmt).

**Result:**

| id | address |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |